# Is there a way to Pre install an OS plus third-party software?

Tags: windows-8, installation, productivity

Every time I re-install my Windows 8 laptop, it takes about 2 hours to re-install all the third-party software I use. Can I create my own bootable Windows disk where all the software I use automatically install?

AND which removes/does not include all the crap Windows installs?

(Maybe even pre accepts the licences for things like... 'opening a jpg file' that Windows requires?)

Software I regularly have to re install

- Revo Uninstaller!
- Adobe Trials:
- Illustrator
- Photoshop
- Notepad++
- FileZilla
- Chrome
- Firefox

Comment: Yes;  There are tools that can build deployable images of a system with software already installed.  Have you research those tools?

Comment: Look into Windows' [System Image Backup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/what-happened-to-backup-restore). If you were using it to deploy to other computers, that'd be a different story.

Comment: Can someone please explain all this downvoting? what on earth has happened to SU.

Comment: @Sickest yeah I saw the question score and came here expecting some close votes.. none.

Answer (score 1):

Install Windows 8 and before going to [OOBE phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-box_experience) boot to [Audit mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744337%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) by pressing <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. [Here install all software](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722413%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) you need to have inside the image.

After you have all software installed, run [sysprep /generalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824938.aspx).

Now boot from the Windows DVD, go to the Repair options, run cmd.exe and run [DISM to capture a new WIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825072.aspx):

```
Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:c:\Install.wim /CaptureDir:C:\ /Name:"My customized Windows 8"
```

Replace the install.wim of your DVD with the new captured WIM.